# MediaWiki: Creating a table using #while function

Tags: while-loop, mediawiki

First let me show you how my current wiki entry looks like and what parameters I've set:

```
{{tracklist|Track1=Pokerface|Track2=Yellow Submarines|Track3=Yesterday}}
```

My goal is to generate a tracklist using a template, which is actually a table. In the left column there has to be the *songnumber*, and in the right column the *songname*.

To achieve this, I created a new wiki template, where I am using the loop function **#while** to count upwards and check if a song with such a number exists. You can find it on the end of my text.

Currently, I do not understand, why my code does not create a complete table. Only the first song gets print out. Someone able to help me?

```
{|
{{#vardefine: cTrack|1}}

{{#while:
|{{{Track{{#var:cTrack}}|}}}
|
{{!}} {{#var:cTrack}} {{!!}} '''{{{Track{{#var: cTrack}}}}}'''

{{#vardefine: cTrack|{{#expr: {{#var:cTrack}} + 1}}
{{#if: {{{Track{{#var:cTrack}}|}}} | {{!}}- }}
}}
}}
|}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is some bug, I can't explain it..., but I found how to fix it: you just need to add table row **{{!}}-** before and after table data **{{!}}**. By the way the **if** statement is not needed. Try this:

```
{|
{{#vardefine: cTrack|1}}

{{#while:
  |{{{Track{{#var:cTrack}}|}}}
  |
{{!}}-
{{!}} {{#var:cTrack}} {{!!}} '''{{{Track{{#var: cTrack}}}}}'''
{{!}}-

{{#vardefine: cTrack|{{#expr: {{#var:cTrack}} + 1}}}}
}}
|}
```

Comment: Finally, thank you! This made me crazy. Probably it is a bug.